# Change size of Python code in LaTeX document

Tags: formatting, code, typewriter, python

I am trying to input my Python code in a document using [this](https://pedrokroger.net/printing-python-code-latex/) template which uses the [listings](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf) package. However I want to change the size of the code font i.e. any mentions of `\texttt{}` and the `lstlisting` environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}

\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=Python, showstringspaces=false, formfeed=\newpage, tabsize=4,
  commentstyle=\itshape, basicstyle=\ttfamily, morekeywords={models, lambda, forms}
  fontsize=\footnotesize
}
\newcommand{\code}[2]{
  \hrulefill
  \subsection*{#1}
  \lstinputlisting{#2}
  \vspace{2em}
}

\begin{document}

This is the code from my file \texttt{mycode.py}:

\begin{lstlisting}
def factorial(n):
   """The factorial of a number the slow way"""

   # comments are printed in italic
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

I tried putting `fontsize=\footnotesize` in different places in the preamble, but this didn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `\footnotesize` to `basicstyle`:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}

\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=Python,
  showstringspaces=false,
  formfeed=\newpage,
  tabsize=4,
  commentstyle=\itshape,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
  morekeywords={models, lambda, forms},
}
\newcommand{\code}[2]{%
  \hrulefill
  \subsection*{#1}%
  \lstinputlisting{#2}%
  \vspace{2em}%
}

\begin{document}

This is the code from my file \texttt{mycode.py}:

\begin{lstlisting}
def factorial(n):
    """The factorial of a number the slow way"""

    # comments are printed in italic
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

[image]

However, you should also scale down Bera Mono a bit more; in this case, `\footnotesize` doesn't seem necessary.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}

\usepackage[scaled=0.8]{beramono}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=Python,
  showstringspaces=false,
  formfeed=\newpage,
  tabsize=4,
  commentstyle=\itshape,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
  morekeywords={models, lambda, forms},
}
\newcommand{\code}[2]{%
  \hrulefill
  \subsection*{#1}%
  \lstinputlisting{#2}%
  \vspace{2em}%
}

\begin{document}

This is the code from my file \texttt{mycode.py}:

\begin{lstlisting}
def factorial(n):
    """The factorial of a number the slow way"""

    # comments are printed in italic
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

[image]